# Flash автофокус

Tags: flash

Есть флешевая анимационная менюшка на сайте.
Подскажите как сделать автофокус на менюхе при загрузки страницы. А то приходится на нее два раза кликать чтоб она заработала.

Заранее спасибо))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеется ввиду активация контейнера с флешем? Тогда есть несколько способов.
Самый простой - воткнуть яваскриптом через document.write код вызова флешки. А вообще - я бы посоветовал использовать swfobject.

З.Ы.: Статья по теме вроде http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/rabota-s-flash/aktivaciya-flash.html

Comment: Спасибо оргомно)) Это какраз то, что я долго искал))))